# Laravel Parameter in every url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7, php-7.2

I have read almost everything in web and documentation but i can't find solution for my Problem.

I have a variable stored in `Session` , then I want to put this variable in every url generated by `route('some-route')` .

In `Session` I have `sub = "mysubid"`

When I generate Route `route('my-route')` I want to pass this `sub` parameter in query string: `http://domain.dom/my-route-parameter?sub=mysubid`

Can you help me to solve This problem? Any helpful answer will be appreciated;

Comment: I know I cann pass parameter like: `route('my-route', ['sub' => \Session::get('sub') ])` but I have too much route in my views to refactor this and I want to make it auto

Comment: Why would you do that? You already have that data stored in session.

Comment: To be clear: you want all routes to have the same parameter _always_?

Comment: @JustCarty That's Right. I have parameter in Session and want to pass it in every Route.

Comment: @Cid User must See this parameter In Url.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to nest all your routes in a single middleware group and handle what ever you are doing with that session in there. OR use the session data in the controller as adding to the route gains no benefit with it already being stored somewhere, you are just exposing it to the user.

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze more often than not, this can be done in the background, are you sure it needs to be passed through the URL?

Comment: *"User must See this parameter In Url"* Is that another great idea from a non-technical manager or is there a reason for that ? Lambda users don't care about variables in URL

Comment: Yes, There Is Reason for that and also great idea by manager :D

Comment: Why not create a helper function that will wrap the `route()` method, and accomplish it. This means you will replace the call to `route()` with your function, for example, `customRoute()`?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze Just a note, I updated your tags a little bit to show Laravel 5.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Default Values feature.

First create a new middleware `php artisan make:middleware SetSubIdFromSession`. Then do the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class SetSubIdFromSession
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        URL::defaults(['sub' => \Session::get('sub')]);

        return $next($request);
    } 
}
```

At the end register your new middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` by adding it to `$routeMiddleware`.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   // other Middlewares
   'sessionDefaultValue' => App\Http\Middleware\SetSubIdFromSession::class,
];
```

Add `{sub}` and the middleware to your route definition:

```
Route::get('/{sub}/path', function () {  
   //
})
->name('my-route')
->middleware('sessionDefaultValue');
```

Since you want this on every web route you can also add the middleware to the `web` middleware group:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // other Middlewares
        'sessionDefaultValue',
    ],

    'api' => [
        //
    ] 
];
```

Comment: Great Idea, but I can't pass parameter with Query string with this code

Comment: I don't get an error but it does not appends query on url

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.7 version

Answer (score -2):

Try this , You need to create middleware php artisan make:middleware SetSubSession

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class SetSubsSession
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(session('sub')){
        $url = url()->full();
        return redirect($url.'?sub='.session('sub'));
    }
    return $next($request);
} 
}
```

in app/http/Kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
 ........
 'setsubsession' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetSubsSession::class,
 ]
```

in route.php add

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'setsubsession'], function(){ 
      //and define all the route you want to add sub parameter
 });
```

using this you don't need to change all your routes.This will automatic add "sub" in the route define in that middleware.

Comment: Please consider the performance consequences of this approach. First, this will likely result in an infinite loop, it does not check if `sub` is already set in the request, so it will attempt to redirect again. Then, if you solve that issue, every link will still end up with 2 requests: the initial request without `sub`, then the redirected request.